# MVC PartialView how to stay in same page after using PartialView to upload?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have three page, It all contain a `PartialView` that is a member data info panel.

That `PartialView` can change Photo using `Html.BeginForm`.

But I face the problem with when I Submit Photo, It can't return to same page.

How to solved it ?

Code:

View(Page,have three diffrent page , but all have same `PartialView`):

```
    <div>Page 1</div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        @Html.Action("_MemberInfoPartial")
    </div><!-- END sidebar-->
    <div>blah blah ... </div>
```

View(Partial):

```
    <figure class="cropper">
            <a>@Model.UserName</a>
            <img src="@Model.Image" class="photo">
            <figcaption><a href="javascript:;">Select Pic</a></figcaption>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadIcon", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="temp-icon-file" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="temp-icon-submit" />
            }
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $('.cropper figcaption a').click(selectFile);
                    $('.temp-icon-file').change(uploadFile);
                });
                function selectFile() {
                    $('.temp-icon-file').click();
                }
                function uploadFile() {
                    var val = $('.temp-icon-file').val().toLowerCase().split('.');
                    if (val.length > 0) {
                        var ext = val[val.length - 1];
                        if (ext === 'jpg' || ext === 'png') {
                            $('.temp-icon-submit').click();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }

            </script>
        </figure>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UploadIcon(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            //Upload Image
        }
        else
            TempData["TempMessage"] = "Please Select Picture! (jpg/png)";

        return RedirectToAction("Page1") <--How to return to same page(The Page I click upload, it can be page1 or 2 or 3)?
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can get view name with Razor using `var name = (this.ViewContext.View as RazorView).ViewPath` or `var name = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()`, then return the view with `return View(name)`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto but it return `UploadIcon` , Not Page action name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you pass current action name when calling child action:

```
@Html.Action("_MemberInfoPartial", new { parentAction = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] })
```

and in your child action, store it in ViewData:

```
    public ActionResult _MemberInfoPartial(string parentAction)
    {
        //...
        ViewBag.ParentAction = parentAction;
        //...
    }
```

to render parent action in a hidden field, for example:

```
@{
    string parentAction = ViewBag.ParentAction;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadIcon", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="temp-icon-file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="temp-icon-submit" />
    @Html.Hidden("returnAction", parentAction)
}
```

you can use parent action upon form submit:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UploadIcon(HttpPostedFileBase file, string returnAction)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            //Upload Image
        }
        else
            TempData["TempMessage"] = "Please Select Picture! (jpg/png)";

        return RedirectToAction(returnAction);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a value to your controller to determine on what page you need to return.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UploadIcon(HttpPostedFileBase file, int returnId)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        //Upload Image
    }
    else
        TempData["TempMessage"] = "Please Select Picture! (jpg/png)";

    if(returnId == 1) 
       return RedirectToAction("Page1");
    //and so on..
}
```